# Changing the Color of the the Menu Items does not work

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, menu

I have created a menu and now I want to change the text color of the individual menu titles.

To do this, I first created a style that should contain the corresponding attribute and then called this style in my Activity_home_drawer.xml. However, this only changes the menu TextColor when the corresponding menu title is clicked but is not permanent as I would like it to be.

What do I have to do so that the text color in my menu changes permanently to white and not Black anymore? Is my way of doing it the right way or is there a more elegant way to change the TextColor?

Thanks for any help!

**Part of my Activity_home_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance44">

    <group android:id="@+id/category_group">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_store_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/menu_menu"
            android:theme="@style/TextAppearance44"
            />
    </group>
```

**My TextAppearance44 style**

```
 <style name="TextAppearance44">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ToolBar style. Check these two tutorials:

Toolbar assigning to activity and styling:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html?m=1

Changing style and items colors in the Toolbar:
https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/

In your case, you are looking mainly for (code fragment from second tutorial):

```
  <!-- android:actionMenuTextColor is the color of the text of
        action (menu) items in the Toolbar, at least in the
        Theme.AppCompat theme.
        For some reason, they already get the textColorPrimary
        when running on API 21, but not on older versions of
        Android, so this is only necessary to support older
        Android versions.-->
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself; I added these to lines to my NavigationView in my ActivityHome (where the Menu comes up).

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
```

Simple mistake, didnot know that there was such a attribute.